# Simultaneous Jordanization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Hello everyone

I would like to have a detailed reference to the  statement bellow:

Let $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $AB=BA$. Suppose  $A$  has real eigenvalues only and $B$ is diagonalizable. Then, there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is of Jordan canonical form and $P^{-1}BP$ is diagonale. Precisely
\begin{equation*}
  P^{-1}AP=\mathrm{diag}(J_{1},\cdots,J_{r}) \quad\text{and}\quad P^{-1}BP=\mathrm{diag}(\underset{p_{1}}{\underbrace{\mu_{1},\cdots,\mu_{1}}},\cdots,\underset{p_{r}}{\underbrace{\mu_{r},\cdots,\mu_{r}}})
\end{equation*}
where $J_{k}$ is a Jordan block of size $p_{k}$.

Comment: @Chris Godsil: the OP made the explicit assumption that $B$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Noah: I've deleted my silly comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $B$, and $V_\lambda$ the corresponding eigenspace
(the set of all eigenvectors of $B$ corresponding to $\lambda$ and the zero vector).
Then the whole space is the direct sum of those $V_\lambda$. (This is your condition that
$B$ is diagonalizable).

Claim. $A$ maps each $V_\lambda$ into itself. Proof. Let $x\in V_\lambda$ this means that
$Bx=\lambda x$. Now let $Ax=y$. We have $By=BAx=ABx=\lambda Ax=\lambda y$. So $y\in V_\lambda$.
This proves the claim.

Now by the Jordan theorem, each $V_\lambda$ contains a Jordan basis for $A$. This basis
(as the whole $V_\lambda$) consists of eigenvectors of $B$. Taking all these bases together
we obtain a basis of the whole space, which is a Jordan basis for $A$ and each vector is an
eigenvector of $B$. Take this basis as columns of your $P$.

Comment: I mean a reference I can cite.

Comment: Now you can cite 

Alexandre Eremenko (mathoverflow.net/users/25510), Simultaneous Jordanization, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/111274 (version: 2012-11-02)